# Adding 2 listbox to tabpage

Tags: c#, listbox

I wanted to add two listbox to a same tabpage. However, when I run the code below, it only add one.

```
TabPage frontPage = new TabPage();
frontPage.Text = "Summary";
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(frontPage);
ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
ListBox listBox2 = new ListBox();
frontPage.Controls.Add(listBox1);
frontPage.Controls.Add(listBox2);
```

Comment: It should add both, but they are probably on top of each other. You haven't set any of the properties, like position and size, for either of the ListBoxes.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by gunr2171, I used a Dock to separate both of them

```
listBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
listBox2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
```